# Matlab GUI How to store user data

Tags: user-interface, matlab

I have a Matlab GUI used on my institution with multiple users. We store the application on a local server that everybody has access to. Now I want to add user information, last server, last database and etc.

My first idea is to create a .mat file, store the data under a structure and use the computer name/id as the handle. Requesting users to login is not a very good option since I have no clue how to store the passwords in Matlab (if you know how, please do tell).

I've been putting this on hold for a while now since I'm never quite satisfied with my approach. I would love to get some input (ideas) on this.

Comment: Using Matlab, one gets used to the "never quite satisfied" feeling.

Comment: If you decide to store on the server take some precaution that no two user will write the file the same time. Also keep in mind that the file could have been changed by another user while one works with it.

Answer (score 2):

We have a similar situation, for a very small user base, we don't need any privacy (we only store window size and locations and few configuration parameters) so we store these are local mat files under users home directory (in windows I guess we store them in My Documents\Matlab).

So if privacy is not an issue you can just use user names without passwords.

I do NOT recommend storing passwords using matlab because it is not just a matter of storing hashed passwords but also you need to enforce permissions on a server (that you said is accessible to all of your users) which is in the best case senario a reinvention of the wheel.

You didn't say if these settings are computer specific, or user specific, or both.

Comment: I do something similar.  User preferences are stored in a "userPrefs.mat" file that is created in their home directory.  If the file is present it loads and customizes the GUI based on the contents.  If it is not then the GUI is setup using defaults. The preferences files is updated every time the GUI is closed.  That way everyone has their own copy of preferences and it doesn't have to be centrally stored.

Comment: The data is computer specific but some users also work on their laptops so users can have multiple computers. All in all your comments have pretty much confirmed my suspicion. It's time to get my lazy ass of the couch and continue coding. Thanks for all your input.